# ARM NXP LPC2378: Is is safe to modify GPIO pin output state via register access?

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I'm currently using the ARM NXP LPC2378 for a project using the IAR compiler.  I'm modifying the GPIO output pins through a somewhat nonstandard method.  Here is my code below:

```
void SetPinhigh(int port_number, int pin_number)
{
    volatile unsigned long* set_register = (volatile unsigned long *)(BASE_ADDR + (PIN_PORT_LENGTH_IN_BYTES*port_number) + PIN_SET_REGISTER_OFFSET);

    *set_register |= (1 << pin_number);
}
```

Is this a safe method to use?  If I step through the code, IAR gives me warnings about writing to non RAM regions, but I'm writing to the register location and the pins are toggling.  I like this method because it seems cleaner to use than the structures that IAR has created.  Is there a better method other people know of?

Comment: On the LPC's you do not need to read from the set / clear registers when updating. A write of 1 to any bit will set that bit without affecting any bits which have 0 written to them.

So just using *set_register = (1 << pin_number); will do what you were asking for, and will be similar for the clear register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAR is right, registers are not RAM. :) It is possibly best to look how to suppress warnings looking inside examples coming with IAR (if there any). There mey be IAR's custom keyword or pragma, thich tells compiler how you're intended to do.

It may also be issue in memory map, as there may need to define register region somehow.

I'm working with GCC and ARM, and it does not complain on any method to access registers. I used:

1. direct and calculated address (`*((volatile unsigned int *)0xNNNNNNNNU) |= 1<<pin`);
2. arrays, structs, unions and bitfields by direct address (through it is dangerous, but it makes code looking so nice);
3. symbols defined in map file with all above (this may be mostly C compliant because of dealing with linker, not compiler).

There is proposed new extension pretending to be a standard I found recently, called [TR 18037: Embedded C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#18037). Section "6 BASIC I/O HARDWARE ADDRESSING" give common method to access hardware (cite from pdf):

```
#include <iohw.h>
#include "iodriv_hw.h"  /* Platform-specific designator
                           definitions. */

// Wait until controller is no longer busy.
while (iord(dev_status) & STATUS_BUSY) /* do nothing */;

// Write value to controller.
iowr(dev_out, ch);
```

There are also `ioand`, `ioor` function[ like macro]s and many others.

Example implementation for iohw.h is also there so you may add support for this to IAR on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look in the toolchain's device specific header file to see how SFR's are declared.  You could also read the advice on page 142 [The IAR C/C++ Development Guide](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupp.iar.com%2FFilesPublic%2FUPDINFO%2F004916%2Farm%2Fdoc%2FEWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf&rct=j&q=IAR%20ARM%20keywords&ei=AZntTPHoIIfNhAeN0e3PDA&usg=AFQjCNHZUNcO4c8uLo9cX5XgQG46WHcNcA&sig2=DLK5fAnA0iVn34EIcTbJ3A&cad=rja) and also IAR's [Writing Device Header Files](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupp.iar.com%2FFilesPublic%2FUPDINFO%2F004916%2Farm%2Fdoc%2FEWARM_HeaderFormat.pdf&rct=j&q=IAR%20__REG32&ei=cpvtTO7ZE4GHhQfM37zMDA&usg=AFQjCNETnDzJsKJySleP2DIZRftlWxLP2A&sig2=z2cMn1f46VcknhNTEIVIIA&cad=rja) guide.

Specifically you may want to either use the __IO_REGxx macros are defined or at least look at how they are defined in [io_macros.h](http://www.arm-development.com/listing/tms470/io_macros.h)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the compiler or the debugger that's giving you warnings about writing to non-RAM locations?

I'd be surprised if the compiler gave a warning about writing to non-RAM for the code you posted - it doesn't seem possible for the compiler to determine what the address will end up being since it depends on the `port_number` parameter.

You may need to configure the debugger for your device.  IAR has a device description file for the LPC2378 in `"C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 5.0\ARM\config\debugger\NXP\iolpc2378.ddf"` that lets the debugger know what registers are at what addresses.  This configuration file lets the debugger show you the registers broken down by the bitfields with names matching (or closely matching) the names used in the device docs when you use the "Register" view window in the debugger.

If you select the right device in the project property page `"General Options/Target"` tab then the correct .ddf file should be configured automatically.  If that's not working for some reason or you need a custom file, you can point to the right file in the project property "Debugger/Setup/Device description file" entry.

Using the right .ddf file (or correcting it if it's not right) might also prevent the warnings you see if they're coming from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Looks great to me. I do it in the same way on other processors/toolschains, memory mapped registers behaves the same as RAM. I do not know how your processor and compiler works and if could have issues but can not see how that could be a problem unless the compiler tries to be clever. I would find a way to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing memory and accessing memory-mapped registers are mostly the same. There may be limitations on how memory-mapped registers are accessed, however. On the LPC2378, only 32-bit accesses are allowed:

> All peripheral register addresses are word aligned (to 32 bit boundaries) regardless of their size. This eliminates the need for byte lane mapping hardware that would be required to allow byte (8 bit) or half-word (16 bit) accesses to occur at smaller boundaries. An implication of this is that word and half-word registers must be accessed all at once. For example, it is not possible to read or write the upper byte of a word register separately.

(The LPC2378 manual http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/philips/lpc23xx_um.pdf)

As you use `unsigned long` for accessing the register, you should be ok. As a matter of style, you could also declare a `struct` with the GPIO registers and access the register like this:

```
gpio_port_registers_t *port = (gpio_port_registers_t *)BASE_ADDR;
port[port_number]->set_register |= (1 << pin_number);
```